# How to enumerate all possible configurations of a tictactoe game modulo symmetries?

Tags: combinatorics, symmetry, combinatorial-game-theory

Is there an easy way to list all different configurations of a tictactoe game? 
For the first turn it is still quite simple, e.g. all these

```
x - -    - - x    - - -    - - -           x = 1st player 
- - -    - - -    - - -    - - -           o = 2nd player
- - -    - - -    - - x    x - -           - = empty
```

are the same configuration, because of the rotational symmetry and there are only 3 "different" ones for the first turn:

```
x - -    - x -    - - -  
- - -    - - -    - x -  
- - -    - - -    - - -
```

However, already for the second turn I can't think of anything more clever than brute force trying all moves and check them against [all symmetries](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/d4/). Is there any efficient way to get a list of all configurations that can occur in a normal tictactoe game (ie once one player has 3 in a row, the game is over)?

Comment: You might try Burnside's lemma.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma --but for a problem of this size, brute force may be easier.

Comment: Also, in a problem like this, it helps to define precisely what's meant by a "configuration of a tictactoe game."  In particular, for the sixth round, do you count a configuration of x's in the first row and o's in the second row?  I'm inclined to say "no," because that game would have ended with the fifth round's x. But some people might say "yes, just go ahead and keep playing."

Comment: @BarryCipra thanks for the comment, I edited to make it more precise

Comment: I second @BarryCipra 's recommendation on brute force.  There are $3^9 < 20000$ configurations, including the illegal ones.  A simple trick is to associate to each configuration a base-3 number.  For each legal configuration it's then easy to go through its orbit to find the configuration corresponding to the least number.  Use that as representative of the equivalence class and keep a dictionary of the representatives.